# Any examples of human cloning in the Puranas?

Tags: puranas, science, birth

Is there any example of human cloning in Puranas, i.e. where the child born had only one parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but the dwarf Nishada was 'cloned' in the [Vishnu Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-vishnu-purana/d/doc57591.html) in that he was immaculately conceived without intercourse:

> The sages therefore decided that Vena should die. They chanted mantras over a straw and killed Vena with the straw. The problem however was that who would rule the kingdom in Vena’s place? Vena did not have any children. The sages then began to knead the dead king’s thighs. After the kneading, **a dwarf who looked like a short pillar came out of the thighs**.
>
> “What shall I do?”, asked the dwarf.
>
> “Sit,” said the sages and the dwarf came to be called *Nishada*, from the word for sitting.